# Question on a specific use case on spring <util:map>

Tags: spring

I'm just trying to explore one use case of using object as a value in a spring map. Here's my example

```
<util:map id="someSourceMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
<entry key="source1" value="testLine"/>
<entry key="source2" value="testLine2"/>
</util:map>

<bean id="testLine1" class="com.test.ProductLineMetadata" scope="prototype">
<constructor-arg value="PRODUCT_LINE_1"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="TYPE_1"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="testLine2" class="com.test.ProductLineMetadata"scope="prototype">
<constructor-arg value="PRODUCT_LINE_2"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="TYPE_2"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a map in which the value will be a new instance of ProductLineMetadata object with different parameters set through constructor argument. I don't want to create a separate bean entry for each key with the desired constructor values. Is there a better way of doing this by somehow specifying the parameters inside the map declaration itself?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you made mistake in your example. Instead value="testLine" maybe you meant value-ref="testLine" ?

Comment: you are right...I guess that was a typo, I mean value-ref

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<util:map id="someSourceMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
  <entry key="source1">
    <bean class="com.test.ProductLineMetadata">
      <constructor-arg value="PRODUCT_LINE_1"/>
      <constructor-arg value="TYPE_1"/>
    </bean>
  </entry>
  <entry key="source2">
    <bean class="com.test.ProductLineMetadata">
      <constructor-arg value="PRODUCT_LINE_2"/>
      <constructor-arg value="TYPE_2"/>
    </bean>
  </entry>
</util:map>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `testLine`s are just test data rather than regular beans you may use more lightweight approach to declare them, for example, [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (since Spring 3):

```
<util:map id="someSourceMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap"> 
    <entry key="source1" 
        value="#{new com.test.ProductLineMetadata('PRODUCT_LINE_1', 'TYPE_1')}"/> 
    <entry key="source2" 
        value="#{new com.test.ProductLineMetadata('PRODUCT_LINE_2', 'TYPE_2')}"/> 
</util:map>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution axtavt ... appreciate your help